# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

While trying to create an ElasticSearch sink connector on ksql CLI, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_JSON_A-0} Error converting
> message value in topic 'REROUTES_TABLE' partition 0 at offset 939 and
> timestamp 1641056495920: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data
> failed due to serialization error of topic REROUTES_TABLE:
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
> Error deserializing JSON message for id 30 Caused by:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
> java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)

The create command for it looks like this:

```
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_JSON_A WITH (
  'connector.class'         = 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
  'connection.url'          = 'http://elasticsearch:9200',
  'key.converter'           = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
  'value.converter'         = 'io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter',
  'value.converter.schema.registry.url' = 'http://localhost:8081',
  'value.converter.schemas.enable' = 'true',
  'type.name'               = '_doc',
  'topics'                  = 'REROUTES_TABLE',
  'key.ignore'              = 'false',
  'schema.ignore'           = 'false'
  );
```

and the data looks like this:

```
ksql> print REROUTES_TABLE from beginning limit 1;
```

> Key format: KAFKA_INT or KAFKA_STRING
> Value format: JSON_SR or KAFKA_STRING
> rowtime: 2021/12/26 06:22:33.726 Z, key: 0, value: {"STEP_CNT":1,"TOT_LEN":0.0013573977968634994}, partition: 0
> Topic printing ceased

The schema for the topic value is:

> {"subject":"REROUTES_TABLE-value","version":1,"id":30,"schemaType":"JSON","schema":"{"type":"object","properties":{"STEP_CNT":{"connect.index":0,"oneOf":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"integer","connect.type":"int64"}]},"TOT_LEN":{"connect.index":1,"oneOf":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"number","connect.type":"float64"}]}}}"}

The REROUTES_TABLE is built on a stream with some aggregations done on stream data.

I kind of suspect there is a null that the deserialiser is not able to comprehend but since REROUTES_TABLE is able to perform aggregations on the stream, how and where is the null coming from, and more importantly how can this be resolved (even if my assumption about a null is incorrect)?

Comment: I would try using `kcat -p 0 -o 939` to inspect what is the exact record at the failed offset reported in the error. Have you tried starting at the beginning of the topic and are there 938 valid records in the topic, or this is the first error you get?

Comment: yep I did try to start at the beginning of topic but the same error occurs.
also, I missed to report some info on the log, I also saw: 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) 
(updated the description as well)
not sure what it is unable to connect to.

Comment: 1) You can remove `value.converter.schemas.enable` 2) Error indicates `value.converter.schema.registry.url` is pointing at the wrong address for your Schema Registry, or it's not running at the address you've provided

Comment: ohh thanks for the pointer !! The issue was resolved by replacing localhost with schema-registry in value.converter.schema.registry.url . this was a fluke however, I'd like to know what is the diff between both of them.

Comment: Difference between what?

Comment: difference between doing a localhost:<port_number> and schema-registry:<port_number> .

Comment: It's just a DNS request. For example, if ksql and the schema registry are running in Docker containers, then localhost refers to ksql itself and `schema-registry` refers to a container by that name in the same network. Same principal applies to physical hosts. You never specified where things are actually running

Comment: got it.. thanks !!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with your solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with my connector setting:

```
'value.converter.schema.registry.url' = 'http://localhost:8081',
```

while it should have been

```
'value.converter.schema.registry.url' = 'http://schema-registry:8081',
```